# how to prefix with 0x and separate by , a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of numbers as follows

```
18 8E 08 83 78 0F ED 63 A4 70 13 AB 78 6C 12 84 86 7F 40 BE 58 E6​
```

How can I append `0x` in front of all numbers and separate it by a comma(`,`), so that I can get

```
0x18, 0x8E, 0x08, 0x83 ,....
```

Comment: What format is the list in currently?

Comment: It's not in any format yet I used hex editor to get this data

Comment: So its just a string?

Comment: Yes it is in string format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***
Using **`split`** and **`join`** with a list comprehension

```
s = '18 8E 08 83 78 0F ED 63 A4 70 13 AB 78 6C 12 84 86 7F 40 BE 58 E6'
s = ', '.join(['0x{}'.format(i) for i in s.split()])

# Result

'0x18, 0x8E, 0x08, 0x83, 0x78, 0x0F, 0xED, 0x63, 0xA4, 0x70, 0x13, 0xAB, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x12, 0x84, 0x86, 0x7F, 0x40, 0xBE, 0x58, 0xE6'
```

***Option 2***
Using **`split`** and **`join`** with **`map`**

```
', '.join(map('0x{}'.format, s.split()))

# Result
'0x18, 0x8E, 0x08, 0x83, 0x78, 0x0F, 0xED, 0x63, 0xA4, 0x70, 0x13, 0xAB, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x12, 0x84, 0x86, 0x7F, 0x40, 0xBE, 0x58, 0xE6'
```

***Option 3***
**`re.sub`**

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'0x\1,', s)[:-1]

# Result
'0x18, 0x8E, 0x08, 0x83, 0x78, 0x0F, 0xED, 0x63, 0xA4, 0x70, 0x13, 0xAB, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x12, 0x84, 0x86, 0x7F, 0x40, 0xBE, 0x58, 0xE6'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the numbers in form of a string, you first need to make a list of them like this:

```
nums = “11 A4 5B DD”
nums_lst = nums.split()
```

Then you just apply a function to add the beginning of string to each number:

```
nums_lst = map(lambda a: “0x” + a, nums_list)
```

And join the list back to string:

```
nums = “, “.join(nums_lst)
```

Alltogether:

```
nums = “, “.join(map(lambda x: “0x” + x, nums.split())
```